# Sorting the colors using jquery

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a color grid with 1 row.Now I want my colors in the grid to get sorted according to this order "blue","red","green","yellow","orange","pink","brown","black"
 using jquery.Is it possible???
Html:

```
<body style="background-color:#663366">
<div class="form-group" >
<div class="col-sm-5">

<table  border="5px" width="500px" height="50px" align="center">
<tr id="colors">
<td  height="50px" bgcolor="red"></td>
<td height="50px"  bgcolor="brown"></td>

<td height="50px"  bgcolor="pink" ></td>
<td  height="50px"  bgcolor="blue" ></td>

<td height="50px"  bgcolor="black"></td>
<td height="50px"  bgcolor="green"></td>

<td height="50px"  bgcolor="orange" ></td>
<td height="50px"  bgcolor="yellow"></td>

</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>


</body>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n6msyp8m/2/

Comment: `<label>` elements between `<tr>` and `<td>` are a bad idea. That aside, have you tried passing a custom sorting predicate to one of the numerous element sorter plugins available?

Comment: I dont have any idea of how to use those!

Comment: Then it is too soon for you to be posting here I'm afraid. Please try and make your way through the various documentation, get a prototype up then come back and ask when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example :** https://jsfiddle.net/n6msyp8m/4/

**HTML:**

```
<table  border="5px" width="500px" height="50px" align="center">
  <tr id="colors">
    <td height="50px" orderId="1" bgcolor="red"></td>
    <td height="50px" orderId="6" bgcolor="brown"></td>

    <td height="50px" orderId="5" bgcolor="pink" ></td>
    <td height="50px" orderId="0" bgcolor="blue" ></td>

    <td height="50px" orderId="7" bgcolor="black"></td>
    <td height="50px" orderId="2" bgcolor="green"></td>

    <td height="50px" orderId="4" bgcolor="orange" ></td>
    <td height="50px" orderId="3" bgcolor="yellow"></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('tr#colors td').each(function(i){
  var elem=$('td[orderId="'+i+'"]');
  elem.remove();
  $('tr#colors').append(elem);
});
```

Comment: Yeah its working thanks!!! Can you just tell me how to store the sorted colors names in an array along with your code.

Comment: @Preethi you can use **.map()** method **check this :** https://jsfiddle.net/n6msyp8m/5/

Comment: Thanks! But my idea is not to display the sorted colors, rather my color grid remain the same and those color names will get sorted and stored in an array.And then as you said, I can make use of map().

Comment: @Preethi for this idea you should use **.push()** method **Like this :** https://jsfiddle.net/n6msyp8m/6/

Comment: Can you please explain me  !!

Comment: Use the push() function to append to an array **learn more:** http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: Thanks! I knew this . I am asking about your sorting code.What is that orderId?

Comment: @Preethi to sort the table i use **orderId** attr,orderId is a custom attr helps sorting all the <td> tags , .each() is use to get all <td> tags by **function(i)**. **i** is used as a counter,then push every <td> we had find in **sortArr[ ]**

Comment: But then how do you sort according to this order "blue","red","green","yellow","orange","pink","brown","black".

Comment: Look at this https://jsfiddle.net/qdk53e6w/ here I have shuffled the colors.Now How to obtain the color name of each cell when shuffling.

Comment: Can u find a solution to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36409014/setting-values-to-the-td-tag-of-the-color-grid-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment60434019_36409014