# Setting values to the td tag of the color grid using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a color grid whose colors get shuffled each time when i run the program.I also have variables with some specific values (red=2,blue=3,green=4,yellow=1,orange=5,black=1,brown=6,pink=5).Now I want these values to be assigned  to the td tag of the color grid by finding its color.
Html:

```
<table  border="5px" width="500px" height="50px" align="center">
<tr id="colors">
<td height="50px" orderId="1" bgcolor="red"></td>
<td height="50px" orderId="6" bgcolor="brown"></td>

<td height="50px" orderId="5" bgcolor="pink" ></td>
<td height="50px" orderId="0" bgcolor="blue" ></td>

<td height="50px" orderId="7" bgcolor="black"></td>
<td height="50px" orderId="2" bgcolor="green"></td>

<td height="50px" orderId="4" bgcolor="orange" ></td>
<td height="50px" orderId="3" bgcolor="yellow"></td>
</tr>  
</table>
```

jQuery:
Here the shuffling of colors is done and the color at each cell is found when shuffled.

```
$(function() {
    var arr = [];
    var colorCells = document.getElementById('colors').getElementsByTagName('td');
    var colors = ["blue","red","green","yellow","orange","pink","brown","black"];
    for(var i = 0; i < colorCells.length; i++)
    {
        colorCells[i].style.backgroundColor = colors.splice(Math.random() * (colors.length),1);
        arr.push(colorCells[i].style.backgroundColor);//finds the color of each cell
    }
    alert(arr);
});
```

Now I want these values to get assigned  to the color grid
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pckshu27/5/

Comment: where did you place values of `(red=2,blue=3)` colors?

Comment: check to the fiddle again.I have updated.

Comment: So what do you want to happen? Seems like you're already assigning the colours to the `<td>` elements?

Comment: Can you be more clear as to what you want exactly?  The grid's colors should change to the color of the `td`'s `orderId` attribute?  If so, when would those attribute values change?

Comment: Each time when the colors get shuffled they must be assigned with the values irrespective of shuffling

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pckshu27/3/

here to achieve your requirement, you need to add up one additional block under JS and a minor change under present JS.

Use of this `$(colorCells[i]).attr("bgColor", colors.splice(Math.random() * (colors.length),1)) ;` instead of `colorCells[i].style.backgroundColor = colors.splice(Math.random() * (colors.length),1);`

The above change has to be done, because using bgcolor under style tag, retrieval makes difference, as it returns under `RGB` format of color code, so instead you can use `bgColor` an attribute under `TD`, this makes easy retrieval and without change.

**Additional JS block**

```
var colorValues = {"red": 2, "blue":3, "green": 4, "yellow":"", "orange":5, "black":1, "brown":6, "pink":5};
$("table td").each(function() {
    $(this).html(colorValues[$(this).attr("bgColor")]);
});
```

the above code considers of an array with required keys and values, and pretty simple to be known, as if the attr `bgColor` value is `red`, it finds the key under the array, adds the value of `Array[red]` as the html under the `TD`. you can even use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: Thanks!! You have displayed those values inside the cells.But what if i have to alert it separately denoting that each color is assigned with their specific values

Comment: `alert($(this).attr("bgColor")+" assigned as "+colorValues[$(this).attr("bgColor")]);` use this to alert

Comment: Can we store it in the array i.e with color names and values

Comment: Can you store the color names and their corressponding values in an array from your above code.Give a demo of it

Comment: `colorValues` itself is an array if you notice.

Comment: @Preethi, very importantly your HTML itself is wrong, you cannot use label to wrap a td.

Comment: Yeah I knew but instead of assigning values like var c={"red" :4,"blue":5} Is there some other way of assigning like                                                                    var r=4; var c={"red";r}

Comment: any particular reason for that?

Comment: Yes Because I am retrieving those values from the database so it may change

Comment: means colors or those values assigned to respective colors?

Comment: I am retrieving the values assigned to each of the colors from the database so I need to assign these values to the color grid given

Comment: if you say color and respective values both are retrieved from DB, then it is more simpler, if you say your backend technology is PHP, simply use `json_encode($retrievedDbArray);`

Comment: But only my values are retrieved and I am using jsp here

Comment: so relating values with color codes is something difficult. seems like incomplete info!

Comment: or instead reverse your logic, randomize your DB content, add the values you retrieved from DB under Tds. and in js you can add up colors without randomizing conditionally. this could be a better option. tryit..